# Trying to find common elements between the rows in a single 2D array

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional String array and I am trying to find if the rows have common elements between them and what that element is. It should look at the element that is in (0,0) and compare it to the element that is in (1,0), (1,1), (1,2) and so on. I am trying to use nested for loops but I can't seem to get it right. Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code and how I should fix it?

```
for(int i = 0; i < times.length; i++ ){
        for(int j = 0; j < times[i].length; j++ ){
            if(i+1 < times.length)  
                if(times[i][j].equals(times[i+1][j])){
                    System.out.println(times[i][j + " = " +  times[i+1][j])
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code checks to see if the string at (0,0) is equal to the string at (1,0), if the string at (0,1) is equal to the string at (1,1), ....; if the string at (1,0) is equal to the string at (2,0),... is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: Please spell out what exactly your program should do and how.

Comment: Not quite. I want to check if the element in the first row and equal to the row under it and then move to the next row

Comment: This code should find all the elements that are the same between all of the rows. So if there is a 5 in the first spot of the first row, it will look at all the elements of the next row to see if that element is there

Comment: Please edit the post to add an example of the functionality you are looking for

Comment: Ok I just edited it. Is that clear? or is it still confusing?

Comment: I think i see what you are getting at. Let me know if the code below makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to keep this as intuitive and easy to understand as possible. The bounds for the first row is [0, times.length - 2]. That way, the bounds for the second row will be [1, times.length - 1].
For each element in first row, I will check every element in the second row. The following code demonstrates that.

```
for(int row = 0 ; row < times.length - 1 ; row++) {
    for(int colFirst = 0 ; colFirst < times(row).length ; colFirst++) {
        for(int colSecond = 0 ; colSecond < times(row + 1).length ; colSecond++) {
            if(times[row][colFirst].equals(times[row+1][colSecond]))
                System.out.println(times[i][j + " = " +  times[i+1][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is awesome. I knew I needed another a third for loop but I couldn't figure out make it work.

Comment: @NicholasRay Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
String[][] times = new String[][] { 
   { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }, 
   { "bbb", "dfdf", "ddd" }, 
   { "dfdfff", "ddd" } 
};

for (int i = 0; i < times.length - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < times[i].length; j++)
    {
        String currStringPrevRow = times[i][j];

        String [] nextRow = times[i + 1];

        for (String s : nextRow)
        {
            if (s.equals(currStringPrevRow))
            {
                System.out.println(s + " in row [" + i + "] is equal to " + s + " is row " + (i+1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```