# Find the most common value from a 2D integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking for the most common value from the 2D array and how many times it occurs. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949697/trying-to-find-common-elements-between-the-rows-in-a-single-2d-array) solution but it's not working. I tried searching but not able to find a proper example. Please help me solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
private void commonElevation(int[][] data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            if (i + 1 < data.length) {
                if (data[i][j] == data[i + 1][j]) {
                    System.out.println(data[i][j] + " = " + data[i + 1][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you can't just print in the middle of the loop. For certain, you'll need to at least check every element before prematurely calling something most frequent. Due to all your requirements, the best bet is just to write 4 loops--for every element (outer two loops), count its frequency in the entire grid and compare it to the best (inner two loops). You could use a counter array with a bucket for each integer, but this will destroy the efficiency unless the data is enormous.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
int[][] data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 2}, {4, 5, 6}};

Map<Integer, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> max = counts.entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));

max.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
2=4
```

Given the new constraints a brute-force approach will work:

```
// find the maximum
int value = 0, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {

        // search for counts
        int currentCount = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < data[k].length; l++) {
                if(data[k][l] == data[i][j]) {
                    currentCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentCount > max) {
            value = data[i][j];
            max = currentCount;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(value + "=" + max);
```

**Output**

```
2=4
```

Basically iter over all values and count the appearances of each of those values. This approach (brute-force) is very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel but this is my college assignment and i can only use an array and for loops to solve this problem.

Comment: @ArpitPatel Can you use a `HashMap` to store counts?

Comment: Sorry no, I can only use the Array.

Comment: @ArpitPatel If you can only use arrays and loops, I suggest you sort the data, and the count how many times each the values appear in consecutive order

Comment: Sorting might not be allowed, either

Comment: @ArpitPatel Updated the question!

Comment: Why do you think your updated approach is very inefficient, and what do you think a stream is doing under the hood?

Comment: @DanielMesejo thank you for the effort but I can not get any output. And what is the Integer.MIN_VALUE? can you explain please?

Comment: And yes I was looking for brut force solution.

Comment: @ArpitPatel Integer.MIN_VALUE is the least value an integer can have, also what do you mean by you can not get any ouput?

Comment: When I run that code it runs for a few seconds and it stops but it didn't print for the System.out.println.

Comment: Is it because my array has 1000 rows and 450 columns?

Comment: It could be you are doing `(1000 * 450)^2` operations, it should take a while I guess.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a hash map to keep track of the values along with the number of times each occurs:

```
private void commonElevation(int[][] data) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            int count = counts.get(data[i][j]) == null ? 0 : counts.get(data[i][j]);
            counts.put(data[i][j], ++count);
        }
    }

    int frequent = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Integer value : counts.values()) {
        if (value > frequent) frequent = value;
    }

    System.out.println("most frequent value is: " + frequent);
}
```